# The method hasMany not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, users and languages. One user can have multiple languages assigned to it.

nocat: **the primary key is a string concatenation example: nocat=A242023**

```
class Users extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'nocat';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable =[
    'nocat',
    'name',
];
public function langs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Languages::class, 'nocat'); 
  }
}
```

```
class Languages extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'languages';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable =[
    'nocat',
    'lang',
];
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
  }
}
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $data = Users::create([
          'name'         => $request->name,
        ]);
        
      $data->langs()->save($request->lang);  
      return redirect()->route('users.index');

    }
```

I also tried to retrieve the ID then insert it doesn't work nocat always null

```
$data->nocat
```

Comment: what is $request->lang ?
and you are not providing notcat value to be saved in user mode as you have incremented to false I think.

Comment: $request->lang is the language chosen in HTML

Comment: Why you make your tables hard to guess.. keep your ids as primary key use `nocat` as something reference and index it .. and let your models and relationships work correctly instead of adding bunch of code to your models for a unsignificant column  name !

Comment: "nocat always null" - bc you never passed a nocat value when creating the user?